# Python GUI- label and terminate

Tags: python, tkinter

This program will ask for username and password. You have 3 attempts.
I want to make this program end 5 SEC after it shows 'bye' and 'Thanks for using.....' which is if I entered the wrong password 3 times but how do I do it?

```
import Tkinter


def win1():
    global root
    global tries
    # this is the main/root window
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Stock Plus system")
    root.geometry('400x150')
    b2Var=Tkinter.StringVar()
    tries = 1

def win2():
    # this is the child window

    board = Tkinter.Toplevel()
    board.title("Window 2")
    s1Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    s2Var = Tkinter.StringVar()

    square1Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s1Var)
    square1Label.grid(row=0, column=7)
    square2Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s2Var)
    square2Label.grid(row=0, column=6)

def textboxvalue():
    global tries

    if (tries!=3 ):
       textvalue=b2Var.get()
       if textvalue ==('stock123'):
           label4=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Welcome to stock plus system, press login again to start using')
           label4.grid(row=3,column=1)
           Button_1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Login", command=win2)
           Button_1.grid(row=2,column=1)

       else:
           tries =tries+1
           label3=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Try again')
           label3.grid(row=3,column=1)

    else:
        label5=Tkinter.Label(root,text='bye')
        label5.grid(row=4,column=1)
        label6=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Thank You for using Stock Plus System ')
        label6.grid(row=5,column=1)





win1()
Button_1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Login", command=textboxvalue)
Button_1.grid(row=2, column=1)
b1Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
b2Var = Tkinter.StringVar()

box1Label = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Username:')
box1Label.grid(row=0)
box2Label = Tkinter.Label(root,text='Password:')
box2Label.grid(row=1)
box1Text = Tkinter.Entry(root,textvariable=b1Var,width=12)
box1Text.grid(row=0, column=1)
box2Text = Tkinter.Entry(root,textvariable=b2Var,width=12)
box2Text.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `.after()` method on any Tkinter widget..

From [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm):

> Alarm handlers and other non-event callbacks

```
id = w.after(time, callback) 
id = w.after_idle(callback) 
w.after_cancel(id)
```

For instance, try this:

```
import sys

def app_exit():
    return sys.exit()

...
# at the relevant spot in your code
label6=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Thank You for using Stock Plus System ')
label6.after(5000, app_exit)
label6.grid(row=5,column=1)
```

Comment: program became not responding

Comment: it's in milliseconds, so 5000 will give you 5 seconds

Comment: @Teeban Scroll down that page I linked you to, and find much more detail on the .after method, including examples

Comment: i got Global name w is not defined

Comment: @Teeban you would replace w with the name of your Widget, time with time you want(5000) and callback would equal a function that will exit your program

Comment: i did everything, replace  w with root, time to 5000 and callback to textboxvalue, but it still did not quit

Comment: TypeError: after() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'

Comment: hmm, try erasing the 'callback=' part, like in my edit